# Can I upload files directly from S3 to LightSail without having to download them locally?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-lightsail

I'd like to write a script that can take a list of urls for some files on S3 and upload them directly to a LightSail instance.  I know I can download the files from S3 and use sftp to upload to LightSail, but I'm hoping there is a way that I can trigger the file transfer directly from S3 to LightSail.  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Log into the Lightsail instance, install aws-cli, and use it to download the files directly from S3...

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!